# How to extract words from a string array in c language and store it in another 1-d array? I don't want to use pointers

Tags: arrays, c, string, loops, char

I wrote this code in C, where I wanted to extract words from `str`, then store them in `char word[]` (one by one), and send it to another function- palindrome. However, the words are not being formed properly. I'm new to this language so I don't want to use pointers or something else. I want to do it in the most simple way possible. Could you please suggest modifications to the code so that the words get formed properly?

```
int main()
{
    char str[100];
    int a=0, l, p=0;
    printf("Enter the text \n");
    gets(str);
    l=strlen(str);
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        char word[100]; int a=0;
        if(str[i]==' '||str[i]=='\0')
        {
            for(int j=p;j<i;j++)
            {
                word[a]=str[j];
                a++;
            }
        printf("This \n");
        puts(word);
        palindrome(a,word);
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use gets another time ,Please read this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used

Comment: You can read string like this : scanf("%[^\n]s", str);

Comment: *I don't want to use pointers* , the array syntax it self is a form of ***pointer arithmetics***...

Answer (score 0):

*Basic things in C don't mean easy to understand. I advise you to understand this code well in order to understand why using high level functions while being a beginner is not necessarily a good thing.*

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    char buffer;
    
    while(read(0, &buffer, 1) > 0)
        write(1, &buffer, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are an enthusiastic learner and have already tried to solve a problem, the best way to help you is to provide you the guidelines which will assure that you will end up solving your issue successfully.

## Pointers

You do not want to use pointers. But what pointers are? Nothing more than variables pointing to a certain position in memory, being aware of the type. You already use arrays, but arrays are memory sections having a type and a size. That section has a start address, so your array [is actually not very different from a pointer](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/difference-between-array-and-pointers-in-c). So, the intent to avoid using pointers was already breached by the use of arrays, but I think I understand what you want. You want to minimalize pointer arithmetics.

## Understandable, implementable solution

You can iterate the characters of your array and store the first non-space character index since the last space you have encountered and find the next space. At that point, you can create a new array of a size which matches the number of characters in that interval and copy the characters from the interval question into that array. Since you are learning C, I will provide you an algorithm that you can implement (this is not actual program code)

```
wordStart <- -1
lastSpace <- -1
index <- 0

    while (index < sizeof(input)) do
        if (input[index] != ' ') then
            if (wordStart == lastSpace) then
                wordStart <- index
            end if
        else
            if (wordStart == lastSpace) then
                wordStart <- index
                lastSpace <- index
            else
                lastSpace <- index
                //create array of characters, having lastSpace - wordStart elements
                //copy the elements between the index of lastSpace and wordStart - 1 into your new array
                //pass that new array into your call to palindrom
            end if
        end if
        index <- index + 1
    end while
```